# NUnit test fails with System.IO.FileNotFoundExeption

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, nunit, testdriven.net, restsharp

One of the NUnit tests in my Windows Phone 7 project keeps failing with the following error:

```
Error   4   Test 'MyProject.Tests.Unit.Service.TaskServiceTests.Save_CallsWebService_WhenCalledWithTaskAndSession' failed: System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.InitializeContract(JsonContract contract)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.CreateObjectContract(Type objectType) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\DefaultContractResolver.cs:line 279
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.CreateContract(Type objectType) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\DefaultContractResolver.cs:line 545
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.ResolveContract(Type type) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\DefaultContractResolver.cs:line 188
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.GetContractSafe(Object value) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalWriter.cs:line 84
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalWriter.cs:line 67
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\JsonSerializer.cs:line 451
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Object value, Formatting formatting, JsonSerializerSettings settings) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\JsonConvert.cs:line 591
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Object value) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\JsonConvert.cs:line 528
at MyProject.Core.Utility.Extensions.ToJson(Object value) in C:\Workspace\MyProject\MyProject.Service\Utility\Extensions.cs:line 15
at MyProject.Service.Service.TaskService.Save(Task task, ISession session) in C:\Users\jearl\Dropbox\Code\Workspace\MyProject\MyProject.Service\Service\TaskService.cs:line 34
at MyProject.Tests.Unit.Service.TaskServiceTests.Save_CallsWebService_WhenCalledWithTaskAndSession() in C:Workspace\MyProject\MyProject.Tests.Unit\Service\TaskServiceTests.cs:line 43  C:\Workspace\MyProject\MyProject.Service\Utility\Extensions.cs  15
```

The issue is being caused by an extension method that I wrote to serialize a POCO into JSON using JSON.NET. It appears that JSON.NET has a dependency on System.Runtime.Serialization.

I've tried adding both the JSON.NET and System.Runtime.Serialization references to my test project, but that hasn't fixed the problem.

The assembly I'm testing uses RestSharp, which in turn has a dependency on JSON.NET. I tried adding the reference to System.Runtime.Serialization directly to the assembly being tested as well, but that also fails.

Any suggestions?

UPDATE: I'm trying to track down the file as suggested in the comments below, but Filemon has been retired. Its replacement, Process Explorer, isn't helpful, as it seems to only show files that are currently being held open by the devenv.exe process. Searching for references to the problematic file yield only two unrelated references. Is there a way to see a recording of my test run so I can tell where it's looking for the .dll?

UPDATE 2: Thanks for the suggestions. I got past the IO issue by using Nuget to add the RestSharp and JSON.NET references directly to the unit test project. Now I'm getting the following error:

```
Error   5   Test 'MyProject.Tests.Unit.Service.TaskServiceTests.Save_CallsWebService_WhenCalledWithTaskAndSession' failed: System.InvalidProgramException : Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.
at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument..ctor()
at RestSharp.Serializers.XmlSerializer.Serialize(Object obj)
at RestSharp.RestRequest.AddBody(Object obj, String xmlNamespace)
at RestSharp.RestRequest.AddBody(Object obj)
at MyProject.Service.Service.TaskService.Save(Task task, ISession session) in C:\MyProject\MyProject.Service\Service\TaskService.cs:line 34
at MyProject.Tests.Unit.Service.TaskServiceTests.Save_CallsWebService_WhenCalledWithTaskAndSession() in C:\MyProject\MyProject.Tests.Unit\Service\TaskServiceTests.cs:line 43   C:\MyProject\MyProject.Service\Service\TaskService.cs   34
```

Searching the web on this one mostly returns references to TFS development. Great.

Comment: Use filemon utility (by sysinternals) and see what is going on and where is a process trying to find the mentioned files.

Comment: You could try copying it locally from C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v4.0\Profile\WindowsPhone71\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll, and then ensure that the project reference is local.

Answer (score 6):

Set "Copy Local" to true for all system assemblies in your WP7 project references for your unit test project. We're using both Netwonsoft's Json and NUnit in our project with no issues.

Cheers,
Jon